# FloatingActionButton position in a cardView

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I set My floating button at the top right in the XML design but when I run my application into a device the floating button doesn't get the right position. 
I would get the same position of the XML design in my device .

My XML design :

[image: XML design]

device show :

[image: device]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
     android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
     >
<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

     <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="100dp"

             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             app:srcCompat="@drawable/draw_menu"
             android:id="@+id/imageprodcard" />

         <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
             android:id="@+id/likeButtoncard"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_margin="0dp"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:src="@drawable/heart"
             android:layout_gravity="right"
             app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
             app:layout_anchor="@id/imageprodcard"
             app:backgroundTint="#FFCCBC"
             app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dps"
             />

     </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/nomprodtestcard"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp">

        <TextView
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
             android:text="TextView"
             android:layout_width="105dp"
             android:layout_height="20dp"
             android:id="@+id/prixprodtestcard"
             android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
             android:textAlignment="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:elevation="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_weight="777.07" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
         android:text="TextView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:id="@+id/qtestockcard"
         android:textStyle="normal|italic"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:paddingLeft="5dp" />


</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Off topic - I'm not sure what your entire application looks like but from the example you provided it seems that you are putting a `FAB` on every `CardView` and according to [Google's Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-large-screens) this is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

use a `layout_gravity= right|bottom` and `margin= "..."` and set the FloatingActionButton in the `CardView`
` or set in a viewPager

Comment: put the fab out the cardView, or put a button , a FAB in a CardView is a bad idea,  Or if the card view is to be displayed in a recycler view better put a button

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you change the frame layout to a relative layout, I find it easier to play with the layouts a bit better, and from there you can add something  like layout_above="@id/imageprodcard" and layout_alignparentRight and TOP in the FAB. Hope it helps!